# Select rows based on time or all rows if the table is empty

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables. One is a production table and the other is a daily reporting table. The daily reporting table is emptied each day. The daily reporting table is a subset of the production table. I want to update the daily table with all new rows from production table. I thought about using a where clause;

```
SELECT ftime, 
       fdate, 
       fdata, 
       fdata2 
INTO   table2 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  ftime > table2.ftime
```

I am not having much luck. I am new to SQL and I am just not sure how to go about this, and can't seem to find anything on the net for this specific issue.

This will eventually go into a stored procedure when I get it working.

Any tips, hints, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot to mention the production table is on a remote linked server and the table is huge 200+mil rows. Seems that a join tries to fetch the entire table to do the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ftime, 
       fdate, 
       fdata, 
       fdata2 
INTO   table2 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  ftime > (select MAX(ftime) from table2)
   OR  NOT EXISTS (select * FROM table2);
```

If table2 is empty (such as if you have just done your daily purge), all of table1 will get pulled into table2.
Otherwise it will only insert the new records from table1 with `ftime` later than what exists in table2.

Make sure you have an index on table2.ftime

Comment: Also make sure you are running the SQL such that you are inserting into your local table (i.e. run the SQL wherever table 2 is located). Pulling data from a linked server works well; but inserting into a remote table will turn it from a batch query into a row by row cursor (RBAR).